# Size of varchar columns

Tags: sql-server, optimization, varchar

In sql server does it make a difference if I define a varchar column to be of length 32 or 128?

Comment: Are you asking: does it make a difference if the length of the column is a POWER OF TWO? (32/64/128/256/etc)

The answer to THAT question is very different.

Answer (score 19):

A [varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242(SQL.80).aspx) is a variable character field. This means it can hold text data to a certain length. A varchar(32) can only hold 32 characters, whereas a varchar(128) can hold 128 characters. If I tried to input "12345" into a varchar(3) field; this is the data that will be stored:

"123"

The "45" will be "truncated" (lost).

They are very useful in instances where you know that a certain field will only be (or only *should* be) a certain length at maximum. For example: a zip code or state abbreviation. In fact, they are generally used for almost all types of text data (such as names/addresses/et cetera) - but in these instances you must be careful that the number you supply is a sane maximum for the type of data that will fill that column.

However, you must also be careful when using them to only allow the user to input the maximum amount of characters that the field will support. Otherwise it may lend to confusion when it truncates the user's input.

Comment: That's no bull. In addition to names and addresses, I have encountered many varchar fields that are scategorically packed with excreta.

Answer (score 4):

There should be no noticeable difference as the backend will only store the amount of data you insert into that column. It's not padded out to the full size of the field like it is with a char column.

Edit: For more info, this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242(SQL.80).aspx) should be useful.

Answer (score 4):

It should not. It just defines the maximum length it can accommodate, the actual used length depends on the data inserted.