# varchar(max) everywhere?

Tags: sql-server-2008, varchar

Is there any problem with making all your Sql Server 2008 string columns varchar(max)? My allowable string sizes are managed by the application.  The database should just persist what I give it. Will I take a performance hit by declaring all string columns to be of type varchar(max) in Sql Server 2008, no matter what the size of the data that actually goes into them?

Comment: In my reading it sounds like Sql Server varchar columns 'autosize' themselves.  So wouldn't a varchar(max) column where the max length of any given value is 20 be the same as a varchar(20) column?

Answer (score 50):

By using `VARCHAR(MAX)` you are basically telling SQL Server "store the values in this field how you see best", SQL Server will then choose whether to store values as a regular `VARCHAR` or as a LOB (Large object). **In general if the values stored are less than 8,000 bytes SQL Server will treat values as a regular `VARCHAR` type.**

If the values stored are too large then the column is allowed to spill off the page in to LOB pages, exactly as they do for other LOB types (`text`, `ntext` and `image`) - if this happens then additional page reads are required to read the data stored in the additional pages (i.e. there is a performance penatly), however *this only happens if the values stored are too large*.

In fact under SQL Server 2008 or later data can overflow onto additional pages even with the fixed length data types (e.g. `VARCHAR(3,000)`), however these pages are called row overflow data pages and are treated slightly differently.

**Short version:** from a storage perspective there is no disadvantage of using `VARCHAR(MAX)` over `VARCHAR(N)` for some `N`.

*(Note that this also applies to the other variable-length field types `NVARCHAR` and `VARBINARY`)*

FYI - You [can't create indexes on `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: This may only true for nullable fields. Each non-null varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) column requires 24 bytes of additional fixed allocation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 37):

Indexes can not be over 900 bytes wide for one. So you can probably never create an index. If your data is less then 900 bytes, use varchar(900).

This is one downside: because it gives

- really bad searching performance
- no unique constraints

Comment: But what if the varchar(max) column doesn't have any values that are greater than 900 bytes?  Would it index then?  I'm confused because a lot of what I'm reading make varchar column types sound like they auto size themselves up to their max as data is entered.  This would be perfect for what I want, because it's the application that should be deciding the max, not the database.

Comment: You'd get a warning when you create the index and an error when you tried to insert > 900. But if your data is always < 900, why not use 900? Yes, they are stored as variable length strings though.

Comment: I don't know if my data is always < 900.  That's a business logic concern.  If that rule changes I should change it in the business logic.  I shouldn't have to also change the database.  That's my goal anyway.  To see if I can get away with taking the concern about string sizes away from the database without a noticeable performance hit.

Comment: How often is it useful to index a long text column? Would even be worthwhile to index something like a varchar(200) column? After all, the index itself would be inefficient. The need to search on long "exact matches" seems unlikely. And pattern searches would only benefit if the start of the pattern is known.

Answer (score 10):

Simon Sabin wrote a post on this some time back. I don't have the time to grab it now, but you should search for it, because he comes up with the conclusion that you shouldn't use varchar(max) by default.

Edited: Simon's got a few posts about varchar(max). The links in the comments below show this quite nicely. I think the most significant one is http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2009/07/11/String-concatenation-with-max-types-stops-plan-caching.aspx, which talks about the effect of varchar(max) on plan caching. The general principle is to be careful. If you don't need it to be max, then don't use max - if you need more than 8000 characters, then sure... go for it.

Comment: This?  http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2005/11/18/when-is-varchar-max--not-a-varchar-max-.aspx

Comment: nope, this one: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2006/02/28/Why-use-anything-but-varchar_2800_max_2900_.aspx

Comment: The first one. By OMG Ponies.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to find the actual link, I was about to step into a meeting when I wanted to fire off the answer.

Comment: And more significantly, this one: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2009/07/11/String-concatenation-with-max-types-stops-plan-caching.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a bug that occurs in an odd situation.  And the comments on the article make it sound like it's already been fixed or is going to be fixed.  Is this the most serious downside to using varchar(max) everywhere?  Because if so varchar(max) everywhere is sounding pretty nice.

Comment: Well, it can be 'nice' for the situation of "We might suddenly need to put an essay in for someone's surname", but when you're wondering how SQL is going to handle that in various situations (particularly calculations and indexes), then you find yourself feeling like the 'nice' is just a trade-off.

Answer (score 6):

For this question specifically a few points I don't see mentioned.

1. On 2005/2008/2008 R2 if a LOB column is included in an index this will block online index rebuilds.
2. On 2012 the online index rebuild restriction is lifted but LOB columns cannot participate in the new functionality [Adding NOT NULL Columns as an Online Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).
3. Locks can be taken out longer on rows containing columns of this data type. ([more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/05/31/read-committed-and-large-objects.aspx))

A couple of other reasons are covered in my answer as to [why not `varchar(8000)` everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654947).

1. Your queries may end up requesting huge memory grants not justified by the size of data.
2. On table with triggers it can prevent an optimisation where versioning tags are not added.

Answer (score 5):

I asked the similar question earlier.  got some interesting replies. check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141402/why-not-use-varcharmax)
There was one site that had a guy talking about the detriment of using wide columns, however if your data is limited in the application, my testing disproved it.
The fact you can't create indexes on the columns means I wouldn't use them all the time (personally i wouldn't use them that much at all, but i'm a bit of a purist in that regard).
However if you know there isn't much stored in them, i don't think they are that bad.
If you do any sorting on columns a recordset with a varchar(max) in it (or any wide column being char or varchar), then you could suffer performance penalties.  these could be resolved (if required) by indexes, but you can't put indexes on varchar(max).
If you want to future proof your columns, why not just put them to something reasonable.  eg a name column be 255 characters instead of max... that kinda thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is another reason to avoid using varchar(max) on all columns.  For the same reason we use check constraints (to avoid filling tables with junk caused by errant software or user entries), we would want to guard against any faulty process that adds much more data than intended.  For example, if someone or something tried to add 3,000 bytes into a City field, we would know for certain that something is amiss and would want to stop the process dead in its tracks to debug it at the earliest possible point.  We would also know that a 3000-byte city name could not possibly be valid and would mess up reports and such if we tried to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should only allow what you need. Meaning if you're certain a particular column (say a username column) is never going to be more than 20 characters long, using a VARCHAR(20) vs. a VARCHAR(MAX) lets the database optimize queries and data structures.

From MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

```
Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.
```

Are you really going ever going to come close to 2^31-1 bytes for these columns?

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to characterize this as "allocating".  The DB certainly does not actually reserve you 2^31-1 bytes anywhere.

Comment: "a username column [..] is never going to be more than 20 characters long" - Fine, until one day the customer decides needs to be longer.  We've all been there. :)