# SQL Server 2008 throws an error "Msg 511, exceeded max row size of 8060 error"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create a row of size 8104 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

How to resolve this error in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Make your rows **smaller** than 8060 bytes for each entry ....

Answer (score 0):

This fails:

```
create table dbo.test
(
    id char(4000),
    id1 char(4100)
)
```

This works

```
create table dbo.test
(
    id char(4000),
    id1 varchar(4100)
)
```

The issue here is *Fixed length data types are restricted to maximum of 8060 bytes (2012) per row*. Use variable size data types to overcome this restriction

Comment: Can i use Varchar(MAX) ?

Comment: yes ,you can .but only use when it is necessary ,but check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141402/why-not-use-varcharmax

Comment: I try to insert data in table. there **1040** column

Comment: I am not sure ,i understand what you are asking now

Comment: @HitendraDeriya, the number of columns in SQL Server tables is normally limited to 1024, unless you use wide tables (sparse columns). Having so many columns in a relational database table is a design issue.

Comment: @DanGuzman I use wide table (sparse columns), but there i get error like

Comment: @DanGuzman I use wide table (sparse columns), but there i get error like  "Cannot create a row that has sparse data of size 8045 which is greater than the allowable maximum sparse data size of 8019"

Comment: @HitendraDeriya, there is still a rowsize limitation with sparse columns, but it depends on the number of non-null values.  The workaround is to fix the design.

Comment: @HitendraDeriya:You need to ask new question,not ask continuously on same question