# SQL - Why can't I compare varchar to varchar(15)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can anyone explain to me why the following returns 'Not equal'?

```
DECLARE @X15 varchar(15) = 'ABC'
DECLARE @X varchar = @X15

SELECT CASE WHEN @X = @X15 THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not equal' END
```

I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm running it in Management Studio against SqlServer 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Varchar variable is not working in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580076/varchar-variable-is-not-working-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 4):

If you print out `@X` you'll see the problem:

```
DECLARE @X15 varchar(15) = 'ABC'
DECLARE @X varchar = @X15

SELECT LEN(@X), @X, CASE WHEN @X = @X15 THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not equal' END
```

If you don't specify a length for `varchar` it defaults to 1 character so your `@X` variable can only hold the first character of `@X15`.

Comment: Ahhh, so varchar isn't truly a dynamic variable character pointer, it's really just varchar(1) in disguise.  It works if I go the other extreme: varchar(max).  Thanks.

Comment: @Eric You might or might not be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7141402/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2009694/11683.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of n is 1 for the char and varchar data types when they are used in variable declaration.

Ex:-

```
DECLARE @myVariable AS varchar = 'abc';  
DECLARE @myNextVariable AS char = 'abc'; 
DECLARE @myVariableWithLength AS varchar(15) = 'abc'; 
--The following returns 1  
SELECT DATALENGTH(@myVariable), DATALENGTH(@myNextVariable),DATALENGTH(@myVariableWithLength);  
GO
```