# How to update a column of char type in mysql to increase its length

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

How to increase the length of a column with `char` data type in `mysql` ?

The following query

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname varchar(30) not null;
```

is not working.

Point out my error please. Thanks

Comment: you can refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513513/increasing-size-of-varchar-column-on-a-large-table-any-problems

Comment: What error message does MySQL give you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `columnname` `columnname` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` MODIFY `columnname` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

please try query given below

```
ALTER TABLE tablename  MODIFY  columnname varchar(30) NOT NULL;
```

You can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-alter-command.htm)