# What is the max varchar length for creating non-clustered index in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, maxlength, non-clustered-index

Creating a non-clustered index on columns of type `varchar(max)` is not allowed in SQL Server.

So, what is the maximum `varchar` length that a non-clustered index be created on?

Comment: Max index key size is 900b. Indexing long strings is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key column length should not exceed 900 bytes, but with SQL Server 2016 cu2, this has increased to 1700 bytes.

You can include max columns as included,though they should be not part of key columns..

```
create table t1
(
    col1 varchar(1700),
    id varchar(max)
)

create index nc on t1(col1) 
include (id)
```

Just to add, from SQL Server 2012, you can also rebuild index columns which are of LOB type, though `text`, `ntext` and `image` are not supported..

Remus Rusanu has a good blog on why online index rebuild operations were not supported in earlier versions of 2012.

Further reading:

- [varchar(max) everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091284/varcharmax-everywhere)
- [Online Index Operations for indexes containing LOB columns](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/)

Comment: If I have description column included in an index, and after that I executed the following query "select from table1 where description='%some text%'" would that be like creating a non-clustered index on description column or not?

Comment: Are you saying if description column is in included list of the index and how your query in comment performs ?

Comment: yea I meant if I put description column in an included list of non-clustered index what is the benefit when I execute search query on only the description column

Comment: SQL can't use indexes on queries using `like`  and in your above case,since the column is in included list..even with out using `like` sql might scan the total non clustered index

Comment: I have in my project description column which is 400 characters length and it's playing a key role in all my search queries(like queries), wouldn't be good to created non-clustered index on that column(which is relatively long string)

Comment: I think you should go with full text search instead of like

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of bytes for a non-clustered Index (pre 2016) is 900:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server

So, give VARCHAR(900) a go and let us know how you get on.