# SQL Datatype Varchar(max) Vs Varchar(8000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, sqldatatypes, varcharmax

What I understand:
If I define a column with Varchar(100) and then store only 40 bytes then SQL will allot only 40 bytes for that cell.
What I want to know:
Now, if I define all my cells as Varchar(8000) then what is the problem? Why should I even use Varchar(100) or Varchar(anything else except 8000)?

Also, Why not just use Varchar(max) instead of varchar(8000) as I understand 8000 is the max value.

Comment: 8000 is not the max value. With MAX when 8000 is reached it is stored in an overflow.

Comment: @Vercelli I got exactly what I wanted. Igor - That's helps a lot too.

Comment: Hi Which SQl Server are you using.

Comment: There are many, many reasons to size your columns correctly instead of just blanket 8000 or max everywhere. For example, memory grants are calculated assuming all variable-length columns are half full. Should everyone on my block buy a dump truck because they would fill it once every 5 years?

Comment: Also look at this answer and links as well:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140790/using-max-text-or-more-specific-smaller-type

Comment: Go have a look at [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) anymore?](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar(n)-anymore/) - makes a lot of good points *why* you shouldn't just use `varchar(max)` everywhere....

Comment: look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/28980502/1805776

Comment: varchar(8000) stores a maximum of 8000 characters. varchar(max) stores a maximum of 2 147 483 647 characters.  refer this url http://www.interviewquestionspdf.com/2015/10/sql-server-storagesizecapacity-related.html