# Varchar(max) storage size in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table in which data type of one column is `varchar(max)`.

How much can be the maximum size of the column?

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980502/sql-varcharmax-vs-varcharfix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick peek at the [official SQL Server Books Online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) would have showed you very easily:

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>   Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. **max** indicates that the maximum storage size is **2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)**.

Comment: @BradTurek: 2 **billion** characters