# How are you supposed to choose K when creating a VARCHAR(K) column? Or are you?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

This is something I've never understood. Let's say I want a column that is storing an email address. I think,

> "Ok, email addresses are usually no more than 15 characters, but I'll
>   say 50 max characters just to play it safe."

and making that column `VARCHAR(50)`. Of course, then this means that I have to create extra code, possibly both client- and server-side validation of entries to that column.

That brings up the question of ***Why not just use `NVARCHAR` all the time*** except in those rare circumstances where the logic of my application dicates a fixed or maximum length. From what I understand, if I create a `VARCHAR(50)` and none of the entries are more than 25 characters, that does not mean that 50% of the space is wasted, as the database knows how to optimize everything.

Again, that brings up the question of why not just use `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: there are a lot of reason for this, for example the case i met is because the ETL tools don't support nvarchar, that drive me crazy and i have to use varchar to fix it

Comment: If the question is "why not `(n)varchar(max)`?", consider this - its a free sanity check. Or do you want to go to your email address column one day and find that someone has stored the complete works of Shakespeare, in the original Klingon?

Comment: Perhaps not the point of your question, but email addresses are a good example of data which has a formal definition, including a maximum length. The Wikipedia page on email addresses is a good jumping-off point for the relevant RFCs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax

Comment: Sure use nvarchar(max) everywhere.  Skip data validation - that is just messy and more work for you.  Never know when a user might want to store the Kuran in Presain in an address.  Did you do any research on what N actually is?  Did you do any research on how var allocates space?

Comment: @Frisbee No, I didn't do any research.

Comment: No kidding.   The down arrow is for questions that do not show any research effort.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894528/does-size-of-a-varchar-column-matter-when-used-in-queries or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax

Answer (score 1):

`nvarchar` itself has nothing to with "unlimited length of string" since it is just unicode version of `varchar`. At present time there are no reasons to use `varchar` (except some backward compatibility issues) and `nvarchar` should be preferred.

So I'm supposing you're asking why don't use `nvarchar(max)` everywhere which is almost unlimited (2 GByte of storage) instead of specifying `nvarchar(n)` for concrete columns.

There are many reasons of using `nvarchar(n)` instead of `nvarchar(max)`.

For example, if your column should be included in index - it can't be `nvarchar(max)`.

Also `nvarchar(max)` data internally stored differently than `nvarchar(n)` and somtimes it can [affect performance](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/).

Comment: "No reasons to use varchar over nvarchar" How about nvarchar(x) uses 2x + 2 bytes storage whilst varchar(x) uses x+ 2 bytes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089(v=sql.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186939(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @LesH if you're absoultely sure it will never be international symbols in your database - feel free to use varchar.