# Sql server nvarchar size?

Tags: sql-server

I have to store maximum of 5000 character in sql server. Which one I can use to achieve this?

Should I use,

```
nvarchar(5000);
or 
nvarchar(max);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implications of nvarchar (50) vs nvarchar (max)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229441/implications-of-nvarchar-50-vs-nvarchar-max)

Comment: Since you cannot declare an [`nvarchar(5000)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186939.aspx), I'd recommend using the one that's valid.

Comment: check this, https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar(n)-anymore/

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl - it's not exactly a duplicate since that question at least was comparing two options that are possible.

Answer (score 2):

`nvarchar` has a maximum (declareable) length of 4000. So since you want to store more than 4000 characters, you will have to use `nvarchar(max)`.

[nchar and nvarchar on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186939%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)