# SQL Query Performance with an nvarchar(500) where the MAX(LEN(column)) < 30

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas-tabular

I have a table with many columns defined as nvarchar where the defined length is very much larger than the actual max length of the data stored in it.  I know that being a nvarchar, storage isn't a problem.  But I am curious if there is a hit on query performance on a table with 32 million rows.  The columns in question are not part of any JOINs, WHEREs, GROUP BYs, ORDER BYs, etc.

Additionally, would the same have any performance hit on a SSAS Tabular Model?

Comment: What do you mean by "a hit on query performance"? I am not sure what you are asking here. Are you joining on this column or just selecting it? Give us a little bit to work with here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000