# String of 40 characters: Would it make a difference if I use VARCHAR(4000) instead of VARCHAR(40)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my SP, I need to work with a string that could be up to 40 characters.

Would it make a difference if I use `VARCHAR(4000)` instead of `VARCHAR(40)`?

**Update:**

The reason I'm asking this question is that to my understanding the memory usage of a `VARCHAR(4000)` and `VARCHAR(40)` variable is the same. I'm trying to figure out why should I limit myself to a `VARCHAR(40)` variable? Why not `VARCHAR(4000)`? Is it because performance or memory efficiency?

**Update 2, Important assumption:**

I assume when we store the string "Hello World" in a variable with either of `VARCHAR(4000)` or `VARCHAR(40)` types, it takes the same amount of memory. Am I right?

Comment: What difference are you interested/concerned about?

Comment: @BobKaufman: I expect that should be very obvious. memory, performance?

Comment: This is a non specific question. Not really possible to answer it. So have down voted

Comment: @BobKaufman: I think I should ask, what difference do i need to be interested or concerned about?

Comment: It is about performance or memory efficiency.

Comment: @SyntaxGoonoo: please read my update. If my understanding of VARCHAR variables in TSQL is correct, then I have a point here. If still the question is not clear, please ask so I can explain.

Comment: @toha: I assume when you store a string "Hello World" in a variable with either of  VARCHAR(4000) or  VARCHAR(40) type, it takes the same amount of memory. Am I right?

Comment: as Far as I know, it is different. Varchar(4000) will take higher

Comment: @AllanXu:See this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/5654947/2975396

Comment: Also this:http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/

Comment: @TheGameiswar: You nailed it. Thank you!. How did you find such relevant posts so quickly? Did you know them before you there is a search technique that I can learn from you?

Comment: I add site:stackoverflow.com to search .Also  i go through all answers most of time and bookmark ,so i can recall specific person answered it and i will add that to search as well

Comment: @AllanXu:please upvote those answers whatever you feel helpfull, as a small gratitude for sharing their amazing knowledge

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Can you kindly explain the "plus answerer name to" part? It would be very helpful if you post your search phrase(s). Alternatively, should I post to SO Meta? I expect this will help others as well.

Comment: For this issue i searched like this..`varchar vs varchar(max) Martin Smith or varchar vs varchar(max) Remus Rusanu`  each one seperately

Comment: Also this meta link might help you:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332773/what-is-the-best-way-to-google-for-problems-involving-actual-stack-overflow-with?cb=1

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Thank you for help. I am finding this link very helpfull as well: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search

Comment: You would use it when you want to limit the data size.  Not often but some time you do want to limit the data.  There is not reason X to have more than 80 chars so throw an error.  In testing an application would only need to test up to the max size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a variable as `VARCHAR(40)` or `VARCHAR(4000)` behaves identically at runtime from performance or memory consumption point of view. But there is an important behavior difference: `VARCHAR(40)` may silently truncate a value to 40 length. This is why is best to use `VARCHAR(8000)` for variables (or `NVARCHAR(4000)`), to avoid the risk of silent truncation. Do not use `VARCHAR(MAX)` unless the value is a `MAX`, as `MAX` types do behave differently at runtime.